# Sorting in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an exercise in my programming book asking me to sort an array of strings in Ruby without using any of the built in sorting. What I have sorts the top 5 correctly but then just stops and I haven't been able to figure out why. Here is what I have so far:

```
numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']

def sortArray myArray
    recursiveSort myArray, []
end

def recursiveSort myArray, sortedArray
    trashArray = myArray
    myArray.each do |num|
        largest = num
        trashArray.each do |comp|
            if comp > largest
                largest = comp
            end
        end
        sortedArray.push(largest)
        trashArray.delete_at(trashArray.index(largest))
    end
    puts sortedArray
end

sortArray numbers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what's happening. From my terminal:

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :001 > a = [1,2]
 => [1, 2] 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :002 > b = a
 => [1, 2] 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :003 > b.delete_at(b.index(1))
 => 1 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :004 > b
 => [2] 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :005 > a
 => [2]
```

Your variables `trashArray` and `myArray` are references to the same object in memory, so you're removing items from myArray on the line: `trashArray.delete_at(trashArray.index(largest))`.

Comment: Arrgh - that makes sense! I thought I was creating a duplicate array - now I just have to figure out how to make an independent duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @phed: I think you're looking for [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup): `trash_array = my_array.dup`

Comment: Thanks, Mu! I think the book must have had something different in mind as I am getting into territory it hasn't covered yet. Still a good learning experience, though!